# Show that $\operatorname{span}(\operatorname{span}\{\vec{x},\vec{y}\}) = \operatorname{span}\{\vec{x},\vec{y}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If I am given fixed vectors $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in \Bbb R^n$, how can I show that $\operatorname{span}(\operatorname{span}\{\vec{x},\vec{y}\}) = \operatorname{span}\{\vec{x},\vec{y}\}$?

I am a little confused on this question. I assume that given $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in \Bbb R^n$, it shows that $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent right? I interpret the question that the span of any 2 fixed vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ will always be equal to itself? Is this correct? If this is the case, is there a way I can show this mathematically or by proofs?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing in the statement of this question suggests $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are linearly independent. They could be equal even, and the claim is still true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\Span{\operatorname{Span}}$
$\Span\{\vec{x},\vec{y}\}$ is the collection of all linear combinations of $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$. In other words $$\Span\{\vec{x},\vec{y}\}=\{a\vec{x}+b\vec{y}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
$\Span(\Span\{\vec{x},\vec{y}\})$ is the collection of all *finite* linear combinations of elements from $\Span\{\vec{x},\vec{y}\}$. That is
$$\begin{align*}
\Span(\Span\{\vec{x},\vec{y}\})
&=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\left(a_i\vec{x}+b_i\vec{y}\right)\mid a_i,b_i,c_i\in\mathbb{R},n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\\
&=\left\{\left(\sum_{i=1}^nc_ia_i\right)\vec{x}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^nc_ib_i\right)\vec{y}\mid a_i,b_i,c_i\in\mathbb{R},n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\\
&\subset\Span\{\vec{x},\vec{y}\}
\end{align*}$$

Containment in the other direction is trivial. So $\Span(\Span\{\vec{x},\vec{y}\})=\Span\{\vec{x},\vec{y}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

For a vector space $V$ and a subset $E\subset V$, the space $\operatorname{Span(E)}\subset V$ is by definition the minimal subspace of $V$ containing $E$. If $E$ is already a subspace of $V$, then clearly $\operatorname{Span}(E) = E$.

Answer (score 0):

If $E$ is a subset of a vector space $V$, then $\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span(E)$ is defined as
$$
\Span(E)=\bigcap_{\substack{U\text{ subspace of } V\\ E\subset U}}U
$$
Clearly $E\subset\Span(E)$.

We have two facts.

**Fact 1.** $\Span(E)$ is a subspace of $V$

**Fact 2.** If $E$ is a subspace of $V$, then $\Span(E)=E$

Can you prove these two facts? Do you see how they relate to your problem?